# Настройки бинда клавиш для своей программы

Tags: c#

В программе пользователь указывает свою клавишу для  определенной кнопки:
например для клавиши старт он указал F9 и сохранил изменения

```
File.WriteAllText(@"D:\SpamerSettings\SFSbindstart.txt", tbBindStart.Text);
```

Затем после закрытия формы настроек изменения сохраняются в txt файле:

```
FileStream stream3 = new FileStream(@"D:\SpamerSettings\SFSbindstart.txt", FileMode.Open);
StreamReader reader3 = new StreamReader(stream3);                                           
string bst = reader3.ReadToEnd();
stream3.Close();
tbBindStart.Text = bst;
```

И принимаются в основной форме:

```
FileStream stream3 = new FileStream(@"D:\SpamerSettings\SFSbindstart.txt", FileMode.Open);
StreamReader reader3 = new StreamReader(stream3);                                            
char bst = Convert.ToChar(reader3.ReadToEnd());
stream3.Close();
if (e.KeyChar == bst)
{
    timer1.Start(); //Запуск таймера
}
```

Но ничего не работает и выводит ошибку "длина строки должна быть больше чем один символ". Как сделать?

Comment: _после закрытия формы настроек изменения сохраняются_ - не вижу сохранения. Вижу чтение: `reader3.ReadToEnd()`.

Comment: File.WriteAllText(@"D:\SpamerSettings\SFSbindstart.txt", tbBindStart.Text); Изменения записываются в файл

Comment: А зачем вам такое сложное чтение через `FileStream`, когда такой примитив как у вас проще прочитать `File.ReadAllText()` ?

Comment: Воспользовался вашим советом и изменил код, но суть все равно не поменялась. Ошибка осталась

Answer (score 0):

Боремся дальше :) Вопрос на ту же тему получает следующий вариант ответа.
[image: пример работы]

Начинаем с того, что создаем переменную где будем хранить значение выбранной клавиши. Для этого правый клик по названию проекта -> Свойства проекта

[image: выбор свойства проекта]

Находим раздел Settings (не знаю как называется этот раздел в русском интерфейсе) и создаем нужную переменную, вот так

[image: пример создания переменной]

Далее пишем такой код...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string _key;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //заполняем комбобокс
        _comboBoxKeys.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "F5", "F6", "F7", "F8", "F9", "F10" });

        //читаем из конфигурации значение горячей клавиши
        _key = Properties.Settings.Default.StartButton;

        //находим в комбобоксе выбранную ранее клавишу
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_key))
        {
            _comboBoxKeys.SelectedIndex = _comboBoxKeys.Items.IndexOf(_key);
        }

        //подписываемся на событие изменения выбора
        _comboBoxKeys.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBoxKeys_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }

    //обработчик выбора в комбобоксе
    private void ComboBoxKeys_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //получаем выбранное значение
        _key = _comboBoxKeys.Items[_comboBoxKeys.SelectedIndex].ToString();

        //запоминаем в выбранное значение
        Properties.Settings.Default.StartButton = _key;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

        MessageBox.Show($"Вы выбрали клавишу: {_key}");
    }

    //переопределяем метод ловящий нажатия клавиш
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        //используем конвертер чтоб значение Keys преобразовать к строке
        KeysConverter kc = new KeysConverter();
        //если пользователь нажал выбранную клавишу
        //запускаем метод связанный с ней
        if (kc.ConvertToString(keyData) == _key)
        {
            RunMethodHotKey();
            return true;
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

    //метод связанный с горячей клавишей
    private void RunMethodHotKey()
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Вы нажали клавишу: {_key}");
    }
}
```